# How to build .NET application supported by default on Windows 7 and Windows 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

Using Visual Studio 2013 Pro, I have built my first small console application. This console app should be quick to run on each computer within our network. We are running at least Windows XP SP3 up to Windows 8.1.

Therefor i have created an app to target .NET 2.0 but to my surprise a Windows 8 machine complained it had to install/activate .NET 3.5 for this. Windows 8 does not have this activated by default!

When i target 2.0, it runs on al our XP's and W7 deviced but not on W8.
When i target 4.0, it runs on all W8's and some W7's but not on XP.

This is the same application.. so is there really no way to tell the OS to use the available framework?

I have tried adding a config file 'MyAppName.exe.config' and 'App.config' to the project containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I swapped the order and targetted .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 3.5 Client Profile.
But when not targeting >= .NET 4, W8 keeps asking to activate .NET 3.5

How can I get this small app working on XP SP3, W7 and W8 without the need of installing any extra frameworks when the client has .NET 2.0 or higher installed??

Comment: Don't include v2.0.50727 if you don't actually want to support it :)

Comment: That's the point.. i NEED to support it.

Comment: The order matters a great deal, you have to put v4.0 first.  If you still have trouble then assume that the .config file isn't being used for some reason.  Like getting the name wrong.

Comment: Hans, even with v4 first it doesn't work. The config file is called app.config and TheNameOfMyProject.exe.config. It doesn't work in any targeted build. Are you sure that this should work in Win8 without the specified target framework?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you simply missed `startup` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Just try to build it again with target version 3.5 using this configuration.

On of the other options. Do you have .NET Framework 4.0 installed on Windows XP and Windows 8? If so, you can try to use this version as a target version when you build your app.

Comment: Good call.. but it's still not working. I have updated my question above. Framework 4.0 is not installed on (all) XP's and when building with 3.5, W8 complains

Comment: @TieleDeclercq just to verify, are you sure that when you tried to launch your application this MyApplication.exe.config file was placed in the same directory where you had your MyApplication.exe file? You need to have it in launch time (not in compile time)

Comment: For real?? I read on MS that this file had to be in the root of my solution so figured this had to be an embedded file?! So this must be copied locally? I'll try this in the afternoon... It does make a lot of sense.

Comment: @TieleDeclercq when you add Application Configuration file to your project VS adds it as app.config, also VS sets special configuration to copy this file with name [ApplicationName].exe.config to output directory. After that it is your responsibility to take this file with executable to every machine you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently solved the problem by placing a batch file in front of the executable:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" (
  %~dp0MyApp40.exe %*
) ELSE (
  %~dp0MyApp20.exe %*
)
```

But this is ofcourse not an ideal solution!
Is there then truly no other way then to pack the necessary .net 4 files? If so.. does anybody have a short and easy guide on how to do this?